# Angular 2 - Pass one component to another component

Tags: jquery, angular

I currently have the following component tree,

```
app.component
 |-> top-bar.component
 |-> menu-bar.component
 |-> bottom-bar.component
 |-> content-area.component
```

My *bottom-bar* component changes it's behaviour if the *content-area* component has overflowed and is showing scroll bars. I currently use jQuery in the *bottom-bar* to find the *content-area* component and check if scroll bars are showing. However, In order to avoid this tight coupling, I'd prefer to inject the *content-area* component (or an interface of it) into the *bottom-bar* component so that I don't have to rely on a particular DIV having a CSS class.

What's the best way to achieve this?

[EDIT]

I've tried the below which is an example of the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve (contentarea is already in my @Component input array),

```
export class BottomBarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
constructor(private el:ElementRef, private contentarea:ContentAreaComponent
{
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.contentarea);
   var gilCounter = jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).find('.gilcounter');
   var contentArea =jQuery(this.contentarea.nativeElement);
   var lastHasScrollBar = false;
   setInterval(function() {
     var currentHasScrollBar = contentArea.hasScrollBar();
     if (currentHasScrollBar != lastHasScrollBar) {
       if (currentHasScrollBar) {
         gilCounter.css('right', scrollbarWidth + 'px');
       } else {
         gilCounter.css('right', '0px');
       }

       lastHasScrollBar = currentHasScrollBar;
     }
   }, 300);
 }
}
```

Comment: For your case you should use a [bidirectional service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to inject the content component into the bottom since they don't have parent / child relationship.

To be able to exchange behavior, properties and events, you need to leverage a shared service. This way both components will be able to communicateur together.

A shared service needs to be configured when bootstrapping your application. This way the same instance will be used within the whole application.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

For example, the service could handle a state property:

```
export class SharedService {
  state:string;
  stateObservable:Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.stateObservable = Observable.create(observer => this.stateObserver = observer).share();
   }

   updateState(newState) {
     this.state = newState;
     this.stateObserver.next(newState);
   }
 }
```

This service can be then injected into your component. The first one can update the state property this way:

```
export class ContentComponent {
  constructor(private service:SharedService)
    this.service.updateState('new state');
  }
}
```

And the second one notified of this update:

```
export class BottomComponent {
  constructor(private service:SharedService)
    this.service.stateObservable.subscribe(state => {
      (...)
    });
}
```